Popper appears in the top left instead of beneath table cell on mouseEnter in TableVirtuoso
Here’s the relevant code:
const handleRowClick = (e, row) => {
  const targetElement = e.target;
  throttledSetState(targetElement, row); 
};

The RowPopper component is used like this:
<RowPopper
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  row={popoverContent}
/>

RowPopper component:
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";

const RowPopper = ({ anchorEl, open, row }) => (
  <Popper open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} placement="bottom">
    <Paper>
      {row && Object.keys(row).map((key) => (
        <Typography key={key} variant="body2">
          <strong>{key}:</strong> {row[key]}
        </Typography>
      ))}
    </Paper>
  </Popper>
);

Problem: Despite setting the anchorEl and using the placement="bottom" option, the Popper is consistently rendered at the top left of the viewport instead of appearing beneath the row cell on mouseEnter.
Here’s a link to the code on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-virtuoso-table-fqcr7n
What I’ve Tried:
•   Verifying that anchorEl is set correctly to the target cell.
•   Adding throttling to avoid excessive state updates.
•   Setting explicit styles to Popper.

What might I be missing to position the Popper correctly?
